# What could be an example of the earliest known practice of data science?

Tags: history

My apologies if this question does not belong here but thinking of teaching data science, and providing its historical development in the introduction, I'm curious what could be regarded as the most ancient example of data science.

The earliest what I have found so far is a passage about ancient Babylonian dream interpreters in the Tyndale Old Testament Commentaries to the Book of Daniel by Joyce G. Baldwin:

> These experts in dreams worked on the principle that dreams and their sequel followed an empirical law which, given sufficient data, could be established. The dream manuals, of which several examples have come to light [A. Leo Oppenheim, The Interpretation of Dreams in the Ancient Near East. Gorgias Press. 1956. ISBN 9781593337339], consist accordingly of historical dreams and the events that followed them, arranged systematically for easy reference. Since these books had to try to cover every possible eventuality they became inordinarily long; only the expert could find his way through them.

To me, this looks like data science, which makes it a tremendously old profession. The dream interpreters didn't claim to know the exact relations between dreams and the events that followed but they collected as much data as possible and observed correlations. Moreover, as these books of dream data were '*inordinarily long*', I think they can be considered as Ancient Babylonian analog of big data.

Are there more examples of ancient data science?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science `The term "data science" has been traced back to 1974, when Peter Naur proposed it as an alternative name to computer science.` so that is the begging of data science. What exactly is "data science" to you?